# Combining DNAT and SYNPROXY in NFTABLES

Tags: nat, nftables, ip-conntrack

I have an application that requires DNAT for load balancing and SYNPROXY to mitigate SYN floods. Absent SYNPROXY, I would put the round-robin DNAT into a NAT chain on the PREROUTING hook. However, adding SYNPROXY would seem to complicate this since its initial, simulated communication with the downstream server happens through the OUTPUT path (if I've understood correctly). The advice I've read is that DNAT should therefore be moved to the NAT chain of the OUTPUT hook, but this seems strange. How do packets traverse netfilter after the first SYN,SYN-ACK,ACK? Does this approach update PREROUTING CONNTRACK so that subsequent packets are properly NAT'd? Is this a workable solution?